# Check that time belongs to interval

Tags: php, time

My event has start time and duration (for example, start time is `22:00`, duration is 3 hours). I can calculate event end time, for current example it would be `01:00`.

So, finally i have:

- start time: `22:00`
- duration: 3 hours
- end time: `01:00`
- point `x` (i should find out if it belongs to specified interval), for example `2013-11-05 23:00:00` (i have date part only here)

I need to detect if event will occur in specific time (if point `x` belongs to this event time interval). Event could have duration > 24h. I do not know any dates about events (these are recurrent events)

How is it possible to do in php?

Comment: Well, do you have start time together with a date part?

Comment: Nope. Exactly i have full date for point `x`, and i need to detect if some recurrent event could cover this point.

Comment: Well, if even duration is > 24h, then it will cover every X point since you don't have any dates with events, right?

Comment: @FractalizeR yes, if event duration > 24h it must be match. I wrote this just in case.

Comment: @FractalizeR and if event is less 24h, could we take it's start time with point `x` date to operate with DateTime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the start time is smaller than or equals to the time of `x`, assume the start date is the date of `x`. Otherwise assume the start date is the day before the date of `x`.

For the example the former is the case, so the start date and time will be `2013-11-05 22:00:00`. With this, check match.

If the start time would be e.g. `23:30`, than the start date would be the previous day, `2013-11-04 23:30:00`. This is required, because if the time of `x` is e.g. `01:00`, you won't get a match if the start day is the current day.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will make the work:

```
$ts = strtotime('2013-11-05 23:00:00');
$date = date('Y-m-d', $ts);
if ($ts >= strtotime($date . ' 22:00') && $ts <= strtotime($date . ' 22:00 + 3hours')) {
    echo "match";
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. the problem is that i can't use today's timestamp. I suppose that perhaps i could use date part from point `x` to calculate possible start date & time and then compare everything...

Comment: @trueツ then change `'2013-11-05 23:00:00'` to `'today 23:00'`.

Comment: in case start time is bigger then point `x` time, this will not work. Anyway, thanks fo help, got it now!

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and it's worth noting that it's not *magic*. You must be certain that the date strings you feed it conform to the [Supported Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

```
$start = strtotime("2013-11-05 22:00:00");
$duration = 3 * 3600;
$end = $start + duration;

$x = strtotime("2013-11-05 23:00:00");

if( ($x <= $end) && ($x >= $start) ) {
  echo "x is in time period.";
} else { echo "nope."; }
```

Also, the timestamp is returned in UTC, calculated based on the timezone set in PHP which defaults to that which is set on your server. Be aware of this.

#### edit:

As seen in @mcuadros's answer, you can also feed `strtotime()` [relative time specifications](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)  like `today 22:00 +3 hours` which works out to the same as `tomorrow 01:00`.

Comment: Magic is that you took start date from point `x` :) Are you sure that this will always work?

Comment: @trueツ the point is that if you think you can only work with the *time* portion of the equation, you're going to have a bad time. You must always include some sort of specification of date.